# Removing the "Brand" from a standard Bootstrap menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How am I able to remove the "Brand" item from a standard navbar in Bootstrap?

I've attempted a number of things, including removing the HTML, but I can't seem to get the content (the menu items) to then fully right justify.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You will have to specify the version of Bootstrap you are using as the names of the classes are different in 2 and 3. Posting a part of your code or providing a fiddle link would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, it is Bootstrap 3.0. I should mention that it is still necessary to show some value (like the word Menu) when in collapsed mode)

Answer (score 2):

### Bootstrap 2:

Simply hide it with CSS:

```
.brand {display: none !important}
```

And if you want to get rid of the empty space, add the following:

```
.navbar-inner {padding-left: 0px}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LdPmW/2)

---

### Bootstrap 3:

Referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174379/removing-brand-in-bootstrap-3-navigation), add this to your CSS:

```
.navbar .container-fluid, .navbar-collapse {
    padding-left:0;
}
.navbar-collapse.in {
    padding-left:30px;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/52VtD/3320/)**

Answer (score 0):

Are you using bootstrap 2 or 3?
Can you add in this question the html you are using?

If you are using bootstrap3, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/52VtD/627/)

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>


    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. I am using Bootstrap 3.0. And the HTML I'm using is the totally stock one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header pull-right">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-left">
        <li>
          <a href="#">About&nbsp;</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>                    
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/95491