# Removing Brand in Bootstrap 3 Navigation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all, I already visited the other topics with the same question, not any answers for me.

Here is the bootstrap 3 nav:

[image]

As you can see in left, there is a "Brand" text there, for removing that in the source I removed:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
```

The results is something like:

[image]

As you can see the "Brand" is removed but there is empty space there which I can not get rid of... .

How should I remove that `empty space` left from "Brand" and let the menu start from the left?

Thanks

Comment: How did you remove the brand? Did you remove `navbar-header` too.. Removing the brand seems to look fine: http://www.bootply.com/118722

Comment: Can you share your code please ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try adding the below to your CSS:

```
.navbar .container-fluid, .navbar-collapse {
    padding-left:0;
}
.navbar-collapse.in {
    padding-left:30px;
}
```

## [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/52VtD/3320/)

Comment: See fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/52VtD/3320/ you'll need to add this CSS below any used for Bootstrap

Comment: `.navbar-collapse.collapse{
 margin-left:-16px !important; 
}` This does the trick but using margins... can I use it?

Comment: Sure- it will prevent the need for the second rule- though note you should usually try avoiding !important

Comment: I mean using `margin-left -16px` wouldn't hurt my responsiveness?

Answer (score 0):

I've have solved the same issue by adding the following in my less file:

```
@media (min-width: @grid-float-breakpoint) {
    .container > .navbar-header, 
    .container-fluid > .navbar-header, 
    .container > .navbar-collapse, 
    .container-fluid > .navbar-collapse {
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-left: -30px;
    }
}
```

When not collapsed, this will set the resulting spacing on both sites of the navbar to 15px. When collapsed, the normal margins apply.

Answer (score 0):

*Remove padding-left for uncollapsed menu; add padding when menu is collapsed using media query. Worked for me.*

```
     .navbar .container-fluid, .navbar-collapse {
        padding-left:0;
     }

     @media(max-width: 768px){
        .navbar-collapse{
            padding-left:30px;
            padding-right:30px;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>` HTML, and adding this CSS worked for me:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav {
    margin-left: -30px;
  } 
}
```